# Sort by a specific part of an element which is a string inside a list

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a list which is as follows:

```
list = [ 'hello (abd)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'leave (aaa)' ]
```

is there a way to sort the list alphabetically by what is in the brackets?
so for example the output would look like this:

```
sorted_list = ['leave (aaa)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'hello (abd)']
```

i have tried:

```
sorted(list)
```

but obviously that ust sorts it by the first letter. I am running python 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda to sort

```
>>> l = ['hello (abd)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'leave (aaa)']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[x.find('(')+1:x.find(')')])
['leave (aaa)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'hello (abd)']
```

It slices each string in the list from `(` to `)` and sorts on what's in that 'slice'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression `\(.+\)`, which will match inside the parentheses. Then [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will be used as key function to sorting the list:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['hello (abd)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'leave (aaa)']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda s: re.search(r"\(.+\)", s).group(0))
['leave (aaa)', 'goodbye (aab)', 'hello (abd)']
```